# What is the issue with my AWS key?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, key

I have to `scp` a folder to AWS EC2. My server is running Ubuntu 13.10 Server Edition. I am using the following command: `tylerschade@ubuntu:~/.ssh$ scp -vr {key_file}{file} ubuntu@{ip}:~/{file to go into}`. It responds with a lot of logging, and I have isolated the problem to the following lines:

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tylerschade/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tylerschade/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tylerschade/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

What am I doing wrong? I have seen the similar issues, but I think mine is different.

Comment: Are you using `-i` option to indicate your keyfile?

Comment: It appears that its either not using your private key, or your private key is not authorized on the instance you are trying to connect to.

Comment: No, I wasn't using that.

Comment: @datasage, what would be the correct place in my command to put the `-i`? and then do I just follow it with the name of the keyfile?

Comment: You would use `-i /path/to/key.pem`

Comment: @datasage, its all running now! Would you mind putting this info in an answer for an accept and +1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is missing `-i /path/to/key.pem` and is defaulting to the keys stored on the systems `.ssh` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your SSH key on your machine is not an `authorized_key` on your AWS EC2 instance.  I'd recommend making sure that one of the three SSH keys listed in the question has the public key in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on AWS EC2.